# How to make sure a given dll function did its job?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, dll

I (still a novice programmer) have been given 2 dlls to write a GUI program to view/change tags from a running software called InTouch:

- IOM.InTouchDataAccess;
- NDde;

Everything works well ; Read(string tagName) works, TagDotField(string) works well

and more... The issue is when I use the method Write(tagName, inputValue).

```
string inputValue = ValueBox.Text;
renamethisobject.Write(tagName, inputValue);
MessageBox.Show("Tag Successfully changed to " + renamethisobject.Read(tagName));
```

In the MessageBox, I made sure that the object gives back the **changed** tag, which it *does*. The problem is that in the InTouch program, the tag is not change. Why is that? Is it an issue in the dll ?

P.S. I do not have access to the dll definition, only its method names. Should I ask the programmer who did the dlls?

Comment: Yes, ask the programmer who did the dll's (that's always better than asking people who couldn't possibly know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any documentation and asking the person who created the code doesn't work out, you could try to decompile. http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx